# Angular (Typescript): How can I set option of selected to 'selected' if two-way binded?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select, data-binding

This is my html snippet:

```
  G Level 3:
  <select [ngModel]="selectedg3" (ngModelChange)="selectG3Changed($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="g3" *ngFor="let g3 of fetchService.gLevels3" [selected]="g3.name == selectedTask.glevel3.name">{{g3.name}}</option>
  </select><br>
```

This is my typescript snippet:

```
  selectG3Changed(g3:GLevel){
    this.selectedg3 = g3;
  }
```

My *select* holds all options but keeps empty, it is not selecting the set option.

But if I remove my **binding** like this:

```
  G Level 3:
  <select>
      <option *ngFor="let g3 of fetchService.gLevels3" [selected]="g3.name == selectedTask.glevel3.name">{{g3.name}}</option>
  </select><br>
```

it shows up the option which matches the *glevel3.name*. How can I combine the **binding** with **[selected]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this html code:

```
  G Level 3:
  <select [ngModel]="selectedg3" (ngModelChange)="selectG3Changed($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="g3" *ngFor="let g3 of fetchService.gLevels3" [selected]="g3.name == selectedTask.glevel3.name">{{g3.name}}</option>
  </select><br>
```

combined with this initialisation inside the function *table-row click(){...}*:

```
this.selectedg3 = this.selectedTask.glevel3;
```

the select will show up the *glevel3* of my *selectedTask*

- My [ngModel] is two-way binded to the variable *selectedg3* and therefore it will hold the initiated variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
  <select (change)="selectG3Changed($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let g3 of fetchService.gLevels3" [selected]="g3.name === selectedTask.glevel3.name">{{g3.name}}</option>
  </select><br>
```

Comment: I have tried before. But this don't send an object, right? It is just sending a value. But I need the whole object.

Comment: It will send the complete event object in selectG3Changed method.

Comment: This is what I got back. It is not my g3-Object it is the event-Object: Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: select, currentTarget: select, eventPhase: 2, …}. --> How can I get my g3-Object?

Comment: just replace type of g3 parameter to `any` instead of `GLevel` and debug it using browser dev tools, then you will able to see that you need

Answer (score 0):

> it shows up the option which matches the glevel3.name. How can I
>   combine the binding with [selected]?

you can do it by initializing your `selectedg3` property within `ngOnInit()` method like below:

```
this.selectedg3 = this.fetchService.gLevels3.filter(x=>x.name ===selectedTask.glevel3.name)[0];
```

Comment: I don't want to filter. Then I won't have the opportunity to select other options, right? I want to have still all options in my select but it shows up the option which matches the option in my selected task. The selected task comes from a table.

Comment: > `Then I won't have the opportunity to select other options, right?` 

why? it's just first initialization of default select value and no more